# How to get provider name based on connectionstrings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Problem Statement :-

1. User will give connectionstring as input.
2. I will fetch the data based on connection string
3. User will not give ProviderName in connectionstrings

I just have connection string, How can I get providername from connection string. Because I also need providername for connectionstring to fetch data.

My problem is There will be multiple connectionstrings I dont know exact count so i can't store it in web.config

One thing is I can't get Database type specific things from connectionstring How can i detect it whether it is Oracle Connectionstring or Mysql Connectionstring.

Guidelines are helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i detect the provider from a user-specified connectionstring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913144/how-do-i-detect-the-provider-from-a-user-specified-connectionstring)

Comment: @Tim Schemelter Thanks, I just saw he used just indexof and (DbProviderFactories.GetFactory Method which also accept providername) as parameter is there any better way for this?